# Do your best! (I can't really say no pressure)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

### FROM:

```
(-)(- -)(> • -)(- • - •)(- - - - -)(- - - - - -)(> • - - - - -)(- - - - - - - -)(- - - - - - - - -)(> • - - - - - - - •)
          6       4   2                           1                                                  3                5
```

### TO:

[image]

---

**What's the answer to this puzzle?**

*Note: The brackets are just there to seperate them from each other... they're not needed once you realize what this puzzle is about.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upper diagram

> is, once line breaks are introduced in the obvious places, an upper portion of Pascal's triangle. Each "•" represents one number from the triangle; each ">•" represents two numbers, the first always being a 1, concatenated to form a 2-digit number in base 10. Reading these in order of the numbers below them, we get PASCAL.

The lower diagram is

> is simply a *triangle*, so to get FROM the upper TO the lower we need to remove PASCAL. So perhaps the title shouldn't say "no pressure" after all. (The pascal is the SI unit of pressure.)

It's not quite clear to me whether

> "the answer" is meant to be PASCAL or NO PASCAL or even NO PRESSURE. :-)

Comment: Well done! It's meant to be the six-letter word you found :) That's the reason I said "can't" in the title (because indeed "pressure" is involved) So no removal needed. Just wanted to emphasize the transition from "row" to "triangle".

Comment: Tick is yours, but if you could just make an edit (the remove part) and the answer a little bit so it matches what I had in mind, that'd be great.